# How can client know the changing from server side?

Tags: node.js

In Node. How I can push a notify to the clients with new information that another client made changing to server, even client is offline and online back.

Ex: I logged on my account to 3 device, 1 on my laptop, 1 on my PC, 1 on my mobile. On my laptop, I change the account’s information but I leaved the browser on my PC. When server send a notify to all clients, the online devices can receive the new information, without offline device. I want when I back access to my PC, I can detect the change from server without HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for websockets.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket